# Present a navigationbar and a non root view tabbar controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to present the account viewcontroller on other storyboard. But when i present it, the the Tabbar doesn't shows up.

This is my code on the other storyboard that i would like when a button is pressed on the other storyboard it goes to the account viewcontroller (See on the picture) Sorry for my english. Thanks

```
        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "UnitedArabEmirates", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UAE")
        self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

**Edit: Sorry for the wrong question. Let me rephrase it. Sorry i am new to programming and swift.**

This is my 1st storyboard that when i tapped the "Upload CV" it goes to the the 2nd storyboard and presents my AccountViewController or as it is named identifier as "Account" but when i try to present it, the tabbar that contains the 3 tabbar items  doesn't shows up. Just the navigationbar. How can i present the AccountViewController that has a the 3 tabbar items. Thank you so much for your responds.

Here is my first storyboard

[image]

Here is my second storyboard

[image]

and here is the code that presents my AccountViewController when i tapped the upload CV

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "UnitedArabEmirates", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Account")
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "UnitedArabEmirates", bundle: nil)
 let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UAE")
 self.navigationcontroller.present(vc, animated: true)
```

Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

Give ViewController as a NavigationController then present it. It will show the tab bar.

```
 let vc : YourViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UAE")as! YourViewController
 let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc) // Creating a navigation controller with VC1 at the root of the navigation stack.
self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
```